# Request public Google+ profile data

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-signin

I'm searching the PlayServices equivalent of this call:
`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/<some_user_id>?key=<your_api_key>`

The call above is documentation of the call above is here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get

However this is a web API call and my keys are restricted to a limited set of IPs. I think it would be a bad idea to put that key in code. Do you think the same?

Just as a side note I would like get the data without "authorization". I mean I authenticate with my key, but I don't want to ask the user. With the HTTP call above this is possible, so what is the Android SDK equivalent? I'm not asking how to do the `GoogleApiClient` stuff I have this already working. I just want to know the right call of the plus API.

If there is nothing similar do you know how to authenticate myself at the rest service with my packagename and signature?

In summary I just want to know the (first and last) name of the local G+ accounts like in the Google Foto app.

Answer (score 0):

To load a specific Google+ profile in Android use the load method for [com.google.android.gms.plus.People](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People#load(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String...)).

```
public abstract PendingResult<People.LoadPeopleResult> load (GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, String... personIds)
```